# Send "any key" to cmd.exe from powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have following PowerShell script:

```
cmd /c script1.bat
cmd /c script2.bat
```

script1.bat at the end of execution have "pause" command, so the execution of my PS script stops.

How can send any key cmd.exe to avoid stopping script execution?
NOTE: I can't change batch scripts - they are 3rd party.

Comment: why not convert it all to Powershell and leave the .bat files in the 1980s?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pipe input to the program (cmd.exe) like this:

`"X" | cmd /c script1.bat`

Answer (score 0):

You could put an empty file called `pause.bat` in the same directory.  Then it would do nothing instead of pause.

Answer (score 0):

The batch scripts may be 3rd party, but surely you can just a copy/backup and edit the content to remove the PAUSE command?

I sometimes put a PAUSE in if I am testing something and don't want the window to close, but otherwise I can't think of a good reason to keep that in.

Answer (score -1):

I had trouble getting the accepted answer to work for me due having an expression in the bat file path.

```
"x" | $Env:WRAPPER_HOME\bat\installService.bat $LOGFILE
```

Error is "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

Here's what I got working (finally):

[PS script code]

```
& runner.bat bat_to_run.bat logfile.txt
```

[runner.bat]

```
@echo OFF

REM This script can be executed from within a powershell script so that the bat file
REM passed as %1 will not cause execution to halt if PAUSE is encountered.
REM If {logfile} is included, bat file output will be appended to logfile.
REM
REM Usage:
REM runner.bat [path of bat script to execute] {logfile}

if not [%2] == [] GOTO APPEND_OUTPUT
@echo | call %1
GOTO EXIT

:APPEND_OUTPUT
@echo | call %1  1> %2 2>&1

:EXIT
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25419252)

Comment: @SRack Thanks for pointing that out. I've editing my answer to include the solution here.